# Computer Algebra System implementation

Tags: java, symbolic-math

I have got it working in a way so that there is one superclass, `MathObject`. In this implementation there is only a `Constant` subclass. I was forced to implement an `abstract MathObject add(MathObject that)` and an `abstract MathObject add(Constant that)` [for reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112003/strange-type-behavior).

I would like to get that `abstract MathObject add(Constant)` out of `MathObject` because its already in `Constant` and I would have to update `MathObject` for each object I add.

I'd like to focus on maintainability and expandability first before adding too much features (this is my third or so attempt).

```
public class MathMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Constant constant = new Constant(1);
        constant.add(constant);
        MathObject mathObject = (MathObject)constant;
        constant.add(mathObject);
        constant.add((Constant)mathObject);
        mathObject.add(constant);
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class MathObject{
    public abstract MathObject add(MathObject that);

    public abstract MathObject add(Constant that);

    public abstract MathObject substract(MathObject that);

    public abstract MathObject substract(MathObject that);

    public abstract double evaluate();
}
```

```
public class Constant extends MathObject{
    public final double c;

    public Constant(double c){
        this.c = c;
    }

    public MathObject add(MathObject that){
        return that.add(this);
    }

    public MathObject substract(MathObject that){
        return that.substract(this);
    }

    public Constant add(Constant addend){
        return new Constant(c + addend.c);
    }

    public Constant substract(Constant subtrahend){
        return new Constant(c - subtrahend.c);
    }

    public double evaluate(){
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the instanceof keyword. Also: subtract has only one s.

Comment: Please don't make corrections that were already addressed in answers.

Comment: This inspired me to try to make my own basic CAS, and let me just say that this is not easy. I don't quite know how to decouple the specific classes from the code, and I'm not convinced that doing so will necessarily make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a compile error since `MathObject` has 2 identical `substract` methods; I assume this is a copy-paste error and the second should have `Constant` instead of `MathObject` as its parameter.

---

`substract` -> `subtract`.

---

`MathObject` only has abstract methods. If it is not going to give any common implementation, I would recommend making it an `interface` instead of an `abstract class`, as that would allow implementations to extend a different class as well.

Additionally, I would change `evaluate()` to `doubleValue()`, similar to the identically named method in the `Number` class. What if you want to have a CAS system that computes using `BigDecimal`, but you want to reuse your code?

---

`Constant` has a `public final double c`. That should be private; you (almost) never want to have a `public` field for a class.

---

## The Big Problem

There is currently a rather big problem with your design: `MathObject` treats `Constant`s differently from `MathObject`s. This should not be the case. Rather, the `Constant` class should comply with the `MathObject` interface:

```
public class Constant implements MathObject {
    private final double c;

    public Constant(double c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    // Always add this when you override a method. It doesn't enforce anything
    // in Java's compile (unfortunately), but you will get a warning if you have
    // a method with @Override that doesn't actually override anything. However,
    // what this annotation does do is that it documents. If I come in and look at your
    // code, it is immediately clear to me that these methods are overriding
    // some parent method. Otherwise, I might look at this and think, "What is
    // this for?" For other examples, it can be clearer why @Override is useful,
    // but get in to the habit of always adding @Override
    @Override
    public MathObject add(MathObject that) {
        // This is an example of something you could do
        if (that instanceof Constant) {
            return new Constant(c + ((Constant) that).c);
        }
        return that.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public MathObject subtract(MathObject that) {
        // return that.subtract(this);
        // Some implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

So then MathObject would be:

```
public interface MathObject {
    MathObject add(MathObject that);

    MathObject subtract(MathObject that);

    double doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, never thought my spelling would be corrected when programming :) Could you explain what the `@Override` is good for, I always leave it out because javac deals with that itself. Also the thing that you are suggesting with the `instanceof` `if` statements was something I tried earlier but I kind of wanted to get Java itself to do that for me by seperating the methods, but I guess that's just not possible then.

Comment: Another little thing is that your `MathObject add(MathObject that)` tries to return a `double` rather than a `Constant`.